# Does pdf.js supports chunking of Pdf i.e it loads some chunks of pdf while remaining part being downloaded on the background?

Tags: pdf.js

> Does pdf.js supports chunking of Pdf i.e it loads some chunks of pdf while   remaining part being downloaded on the background? How ?

Answer (score 2):

PDF.js automatically detects if the browser and the server can handle chunk loading properly. PDF.js uses XHR in the worker code (pdf.worker.js) to fetch entire binary PDF data as arraybuffer. It might abort initial full request and use several HTTP range requests the get portions of the data if server script signals that it can support range requests. (Benefit: first page is showing faster.) If server script wrongfully sets HTTP headers or not properly processeses HTTP requests, PDF.js performance suffers. Also, if browser can load binary data progressively if will not abort the main requests and continue loading data using main request in parallel.

Few notes about browsers limitations when chunking request does not work:

- Safari has defect with range requests caching so chunking disabled for Safari (and any iOS browser);
- IE9 has no XHR arraybuffer support.